# How to show custom update/modifications text when I publish my outlook-addin. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, outlook, outlook-addin

Recently I have created an Addin for my outlook 2013 in VB.net. I usually do a lot of modifications on this application especially in the beginning. These modification automatically download when a user starts its outlook as soon I publish the project.

The question I have, and which I cant seem to figure out how to do it is:

Is it possible to show the user some kind of custom made UPDATE pop-up text when outlook automatically updates the addin? 
So a user starts its outlook, then the outlook usually executes the updates pretty fast and then I want them to show some kind of message which contains the updates being done.

I have no clue if this is possible though and I cant seem to find an option for it in the publish tab of visual studio. Can this be done with code, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickOnce doesn't provide anything for that. See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

In the new version of the software which you are going to publish you may add a message box. It can be shown for the first run only. For example, add a windows registry key which indicates that the add-in (new version) is run for the first time. Reading the value at runtime will help you to decide whether such message box is required or not.